# Cannot update MySQL using PDO::PARAM_LOB on a serialized array.No error is being thrown

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running a test to serialize an array using PHP, in order to update my database I use the PDO extension. I have tried changing the code a bit, but there is no error to be catched by the try block. I have other functions where I successfully updated other tables, the only diferense here is the PDO::PARAM_LOB line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
require("database.php");

try {
    $test = array('15525');
    array_push($test, '12345');
    var_dump($test);
    $stest = serialize($test);
    var_dump($stest) ;
    $dapartmentToUpdate = 3;
    $result = $db->prepare("
        UPDATE departments_employees 
        SET employee_id = ?  
        WHERE department_id = ?
        ");
    $result ->bindParam(1,$stest,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $result ->bindParam(2,$departmentToUpdate,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result -> execute();


    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "Could not write to database for some odd reason";
    exit;
    }

?>
```

I must add that by taking the query directly to SQL makes it run just fine, so I must be missing something. The statement on SQL looks like

```
  UPDATE departments_employees 
  SET employee_id = 'a:2:{i:0;s:5:"15525";i:1;s:5:"12345";}' 
  WHERE department_id = 3
```

config.php are just some environment constants, user, password and some other private stuff, database.php looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once ('config.php');

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME .";port=" . DB_PORT,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Could not connect to the database.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: what is your database.php

Comment: it is a file which contains the PDO object instanziation, i'll add it to the post

Comment: 1. why PARAM_LOB? Any reason for using this mode?. 2. What is the outcome of this code? Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: 1. Actually I was reading about it a couple of days ago, I was looking for a way to store a an array of numbers into MySQL, this seemed simple enough, store it as a BLOB on MySQL and unserialize as needed, I see you are very proficient with PDO, PHP and MySQL, so I could try something else if you think it might be better.
2. The code just runs, but the change is not taking place on MySQL, it prints to screen the var_dumo, I usually catch an error when something goes wrong and I think the only reason it doesn't work it's because I am fairly new to using BLOB data.

Comment: Storing serialized arrays in a database is a VERY bad idea. Either way, no PARAM_LOB should be used byt regular PARAM_STR. How do you know that  the change is not taking place? What is the value before update? What is it after?

Comment: I go into the table and verify the values, I allowed the field to accept NULL values, it simply stays NULL, but if I run an SQL statement such as the one above the values are updated. 
Before trying this solution I was using relational tables and calling what I needed using JOINs , maybe I should go back to that solution instead. 
The final purpose of this function would be to assign a bunch of employees to a department,later on  assign some tasks to each employee in the array each week but not all employees have all tasks and such.

Comment: How is that it is a bad idea to store arrays in a database? 
I read it was against good practices of a relational database, but is it buggy or it might break something ?
If it is for a security reason the app is going to be contained at my office's intranet  and no info besides the employee id's is being disclosed.

Comment: Its a bad idea because it can cause security flaws serializing data, you don't know what it is **before**, you also cannot query through serialized data since its not normalised inside the database @delcueto Why not create a seperate table and cross reference? ie: user table can have a department ID and which references a deparment table (add a department ID to that table) - just a futher notice, don't implode or explode using stored db arrays

Comment: @KyleThomas I already have that structure, I can create a relationship between departments and employees, departments with tasks, but not employees and tasks. Later on I'll need to create a script which will load all the tasks an employee is assigned to. Does this means that I need to create a relation between each employee and each tasks ?. Having lists of tasks and an array of employees assigned to them seem simpler than creating that structure. Either way, I better go back and analyze my database structure. Thanks a lot for the help guys, it's nice to have someone to have bounce ideas with.

Comment: If you have MySQL 5.7 and higher installed then it would be a good idea to work with JSON Data Type fields to pass in a JSON format your employers tasks only. But fields such as `employer_id` it should be better to declare it as integer, probably it will have to be a key (you judge that based on your db schema). Creating some MySQL Functions or Stored Procedures to handle in a way your JSON Data Type values could be handy at that point.

Comment: Yeah, you should always include a reference to something belonging to that user. Then use the `inner join` in SQL for querying data: `SELECT * FROM users inner join tasks ON tasks.uid = users.uid inner join departments ON deparments.uid = tasks.uid` (something similar) @delcueto

Comment: regarding security about it staying on a localhost server, it's still *bad practice* to be using it @delcueto

Comment: I'll explore the JSON solution, it seems I have a lot of reading in front of me. Thanks again for your time guys.